# What makes a treat only suitable for a certain age range?

Tags: dogs, diet, safety, junior-pets, treats

About a month ago I bought a bag of treats for my puppy (cracker-like, bone shaped). But when I got home I discovered that the bag said it was suitable for puppies 6 months old and older.

I don't mind storing the treats for some time (until he's 6 months old) but it got me thinking:

### What makes a treat only suitable for a certain age?

I would assume nothing there would be *toxic*, but perhaps something in the ingredients is hard to digest for a young stomach?

Comment: choking risk maby?

Comment: Hi Roflo! What's the name of the treat?

Comment: Hi @RebeccaRVT, I don't know the name of the treat by heart. If it's important I can check it out when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen that before as well and couldn't find any significant reason that's directly obvious.

The only one I could come up with are indeed the ingredients: A puppy needs a different relative amount of calcium and phosphorus (more calcium) since the young dog's body won't be able to control the ratio as well as an adult dog.

Answer (score 1):

Other reasons could be:

- dog needs to be old enough to eat an ingredient;
- treat is too high in calories for a younger dog;
- dog needs to be older enough to bite treat, rather than slobbering the cracker into a gooey mess;
- treat is too hard for a young puppy (or old dog).

Answer (score 1):

Because a young puppy needs a much  more fat and sugar packed diet than what a 6 month old would need and so is tailored to suit the needs of different ages, similarly to an old dog needing less fat but more fibre.